# Can't get VisualStateGroup.Transitions to work in templated control

Tags: user-controls, windows-runtime, uwp, visualstatemanager

I am creating a templated control. The idea is to create an expanding control. It will have a Header and a Details property each corresponding to a `ContentPresenter`. The user will be able to tap on the Header and the Details section will expand with an animation. When the user taps the header again the Details section will retract with another animation.

I am using Visual States and `VisualTransitions` to achieve that. Here is my code.

```
[TemplatePart(Name ="Header", Type=typeof(ContentPresenter))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "Details", Type = typeof(ContentPresenter))]
[TemplateVisualState(GroupName ="ExpandStates",Name ="Expanded")]
[TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "ExpandStates", Name = "Compact")]
public sealed class ExpandingItem : Control
{

    private ContentPresenter header;
    private bool isExpanded;

    public ExpandingItem()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ExpandingItem);
    }

    public FrameworkElement Header
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Header.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(ExpandingItem), new PropertyMetadata(default(FrameworkElement)));


    public FrameworkElement Details
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(DetailsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DetailsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Details.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DetailsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Details", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(ExpandingItem), new PropertyMetadata(default(FrameworkElement)));



    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        if (header != null)
        {
            header.Tapped -= HeaderTapped;
        }

        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        header = (ContentPresenter)GetTemplateChild("Header");
        header.Tapped += HeaderTapped;
    }

    private void HeaderTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isExpanded)
        {
            Retract();
            OnStateChanged(new ExpandItemEventArgs(false));
        }
        else
        {
            Expand();
            OnStateChanged(new ExpandItemEventArgs(true));
        }
        isExpanded = !isExpanded;
    }


    public void Expand()
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Expanded", true);
    }

    public void Retract()
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Compact", true);
    }

    public EventHandler<ExpandItemEventArgs> StateChanged;
    private void OnStateChanged(ExpandItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Make a temporary copy of the event to avoid possibility of
        // a race condition if the last subscriber unsubscribes
        // immediately after the null check and before the event is raised.
        EventHandler<ExpandItemEventArgs> handler = StateChanged;

        // Event will be null if there are no subscribers
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the template

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ExpandingItem" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ExpandingItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="Compact" To="Expanded">
                                    <VisualTransition.Storyboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <FadeInThemeAnimation
                                                TargetName="Details"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition.Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition From="Expanded" To="Compact">
                                    <VisualTransition.Storyboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation
                                                TargetName="Details"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition.Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Compact"/>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Details.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeInThemeAnimation
                                                TargetName="Details"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>                        
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="Header"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>

                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="Details"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Details}"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"/>

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I am using the fadein/fadeout animation as it is a simple animation but ideally I would like to use something like the splitopen/splitclose animation.

The problem is that even though the transition between the states happens normally. The animations never occur. Can you help me identify the problem?

Edit: Here is the code for the `ExpandItemEventArgs`

```
 public class ExpandItemEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly bool isExpanded;

    public ExpandItemEventArgs(bool isExpanded)
    {
        this.isExpanded = isExpanded;
    }

    public bool IsExpanded => isExpanded;
}
```

Comment: How is your `ExpandItemEventArgs`? Can you post this code?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I added the ExpandItemEventArgs. I don't think they could affect the visual state transitions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that even though the transition between the states happens normally. The animations never occur. Can you help me identify the problem?

This is because your `VisualTransition From="Compact" To="Expanded"`, at first you didn't make your control enter the `VisualState` named `Compact`. And when you `<VisualTransition From="Expanded" To="Compact">`, since you didn't set the `Visibility` property for your `Details`, it will erase the last `VisualState` and go back to Collapsed state directly, the animation won't be shown.

Here I modified your code, and in order to make the animation of fade in and out more obviously, I changed the animations also:

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:ExpandingItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ExpandingItem">
                <Grid Name="RootGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition To="Expanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:3">
                                    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeIn">
                                        <DoubleAnimation From="0.1" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Details" Duration="0:0:3">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <CubicEase />
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition From="Expanded" To="Compact" GeneratedDuration="0:0:2.5">
                                    <VisualTransition.Storyboard>
                                        <Storyboard x:Name="FadeOut">
                                            <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Details" Duration="0:0:3">
                                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase />
                                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition.Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Details.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Details.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Details.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <ContentPresenter
                    x:Name="Header"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" />

                    <ContentPresenter
                    x:Name="Details"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Details}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Code I modified in behind:

```cs
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    if (header != null)
    {
        header.Tapped -= HeaderTapped;
    }

    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Compact", true); //Go to compact state at first

    header = (ContentPresenter)GetTemplateChild("Header");
    header.Tapped += HeaderTapped;
}

public void Expand()
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", true); //Go to Normal state firstly when it expanded, in order to make it visible.
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Expanded", true);
}
```

Rendering Image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I see what I was doing wrong. I will accept your answer but will also suggest a couple of edits to make it better.

Comment: @Corcus, you're welcome, and it's very kind of you that you edit to make it better, look forward to it.